# Sum over a date range per group in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table with certain dates and product types

```
Product  Process_Date Prod_Count
A         2015-08-01    2
A         2015-09-03    2
A         2015-05-06    3
B         2014-01-01    4
B         2014-12-31    5
```

I am trying to compute for each row, the count of product entries in the last 6 months from the process date (including the process_date). So the output should look like

```
Product  Process_Date  Count
A         2015-08-01    5
A         2015-09-03    7
A         2015-05-06    3
B         2014-01-01    4
B         2014-12-31    5
```

Currently I am doing a self-join

```
SELECT
q.Product, q.Process_Date, SUM(Prod_Count) AS num_180days
FROM tableT p
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT Product, Process_Date
  FROM tableT
) q
ON p.Product = q.Product
WHERE Process_Date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(q.Process_Date, 180) AND q.Process_Date
GROUP BY q.Product, q.Process_Date;
```

This query takes really long since the table is pretty big. I was wondering if  there is an alternative using windowed functions to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: The subquery appears to be unnecessary. Why can't you just group on tableT.Product and tableT.Process_Date? Subqueries are bad news for performance in Hive.

Comment: @chipmunkofdoom2 Could you elaborate how you can avoid the subquery for the group by?

Comment: By doing `GROUP BY p.Product, p.Process_Date; `. The subquery doesn't appear to be doing anything. It's simply pulling distinct Products and Process_Dates from tableT, then joining back to tableT. This shouldn't affect the row counts at all. Joining on `p.Product` and `p.Process_Date` should give you the same result.

Comment: If you are joining on just `Product`, every row that has that product will join to every possible combination of that product and process date in the table. So it should increase the rows a lot

Comment: Hm. So I see that now. Okay, so different question, why would you want to do that? You're duplicating data, which is going to affect any aggregates.

Comment: To be able to group by distinct product and process date and sum the prod count over the group. Everything in the group would be in the range of the process date and the process date - 180 days date.

Answer (score 6):

This can be accomplished simply by using Hive windows analytic functions although it's not obvious that this is true given the state of the documentation. I find that the official Hive documentation is out-of-date and often incorrect. I found this treasure by reading through the Hive JIRAs. For more information on additional window analytic function capabilities here is the original JIRI: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4112.

There is a strange restriction that the window analytic function can't contain multiplication of integers. The work around is to pre-multiply hence 15552000 = 60*60*24*180 seconds or 180 days.

```
SELECT
    product,
    process_date,
    prod_count,
    sum(prod_count) OVER (
        PARTITION BY product 
        ORDER BY unix_timestamp(process_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') ASC 
        RANGE BETWEEN 15552000 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) as count
FROM tableT
```

I hope this helps!